# Updating layer attribute in QGIS processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

In a QGIS processing script I try to update an attribute value in a feature with changeAttributeValue but I am not able to.

I'm following:
https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html#processing-scripts

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination,
                       )
#from qgis import processing



class SaveAttributesAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """Saves the attributes of a vector layer to a CSV file."""
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    X_FIELD = 'x_field' # champ centroid X
    Y_FIELD = 'y_field' # champ centroid Y
    SURFACE_FIELD = 'surface_field'  # champ surface



def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr('Input layer'),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
        )
    )
    self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterField(
            self.X_FIELD,
            'Champ centroide X',
            '',
            self.INPUT))
    self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterField(
            self.Y_FIELD,
            'Champ centroide Y',
            '',
            self.INPUT))
    self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterField(
            self.SURFACE_FIELD,
            'Champ Surface',
            '',
            self.INPUT))


def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
    csv = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)
    
    x_field = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.X_FIELD,
        context)
    y_field = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.Y_FIELD,
        context)
    surface_field = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SURFACE_FIELD,
        context)

    fieldnames = [field.name() for field in source.fields()]

    # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
    # get features from source
    total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
    
    features = source.getFeatures()
    
    fieldIdx = source.fields().indexFromName(surface_field)
    feedback.pushInfo(str(fieldIdx))
    feedback.pushInfo(surface_field)
    feedback.pushInfo(x_field)
    feedback.pushInfo(y_field)

    
    for current, f in enumerate(features):
         # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            break
        feedback.pushInfo(str(f.geometry().centroid()))
        feedback.pushInfo(str(f.geometry().area()))
        feedback.pushInfo(str(f.id()))
        #changeAttributeValue(f.id(),source.fields().indexFromName(surface_field), f.geometry().area())            
          
          

          # Update the progress bar
        feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

    return {self.OUTPUT: csv}

def name(self):
    return 'save_attributes'

def displayName(self):
    return self.tr('Update X,Y,area')

def group(self):
    return self.tr(self.groupId())

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def tr(self, string):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

def createInstance(self):
    return SaveAttributesAlgorithm()
```

Comment: What do you mean by not able? Do you get errors?

Comment: In tried features.changeAttributeValue(f.id(),source.fields().indexFromName(surface_field), f.geometry().area()) but it doesnt work

Comment: the error is Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 90, in processAlgorithm
AttributeError: 'QgsFeatureIterator' object has no attribute 'changeAttributeValue'

Comment: Thanks for the ansewer but f.changeAttributeValue gives AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'changeAttributeValue'

Comment: You cannot call `changeAttributeValue` from `features` (which is a `QgsFeatureIterator`). You need to call it from a `QgsVectorLayer` (`source` object in your case) if you open an edit session. That's well documented in the PyQGIS Cookbook. Have a look at: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers

Answer (score 1):

I found the way by replacing `source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)` with `source = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)`